# How to do a sum in python

Tags: python, function, sum

I was wondering how one can represent a sum in python without loops like [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html)

where we have:

```
def rosen(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)
```

My function is the following: `V(theta) = Sum(i=1->N)[a0*(cos(i*theta)]`

Thank you in advance for your help :):)

Comment: You mean without Numpy? How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
def V(theta,N):
    return sum(a0*(cos(i*theta) for i in range(1,N+1))
print V(theta,N)
```

or you can use `lambda`:

```
V =lambda theta,N : sum(a0*(cos(i*theta) for i in range(1,N+1))   
print V(theta,N)
```

Comment: @FaycalF thank us by accepting any of these answers, just check the tick mark on the left side of the solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Your formula is:

> V(theta) = Sum(i=1->N)[a0*(cos(i*theta)]

which means: sum all values of `a0*(cos(i*theta)` for a given value `theta` in the range `1` to and including `N`.

This becomes something like this in Python:

```
def V(theta, N):
    return sum(a0*(cos(i*theta)) for i in range(1, N + 1))
```

Note that you have to pass `theta` and `N` to the function. Also note that we are using `N + 1` to make sure `N` is included (as `range` iterates over the values until, but not including, the last value).

Comment: Oh thank you! But then how can I save the data at each increment in a texte file? In a for loop I would have used fprintf but here I dont see how can I insert it?

Answer (score 0):

Your shown example uses no math functions, just basic arithmetical operations. That's why it works as shown, but math.cos doesn't support lists and so will not work this way.
If you really want to get around without any for, you should use numpy. Numpy's math functions support lists (actually arrays).
This way you can write something like:

```
from numpy import *
def fun(theta):
    return a0*sum(cos(arange(1,N+1)*theta))
```

Should you be doing a lot of this kind of calculations, it is best to use numpy.