# Python least square

Tags: python

I just have a little problem with my code:

```
def pval(x, p, i):
return sum(p[0]*(cos(i*x)) for i in range(1, p[1] + 1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()

x, y = loadtxt("Data.txt" , unpack=True)
errfunc = lambda p, x, y: pval(p, x, i) - y # Distance to the target function
p0 = [49, 100] # Initial guess for the parameters
p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0[:], args=(x, y))
```

I come up with a prompt saying name 'optimize' is not defined but I don't see where the error come from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a sum in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167660/how-to-do-a-sum-in-python) Please don't do question spam!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the last line: `p1, success = optimize.leastsq(...)` (which the error message traceback points out).

Python doesn't know what you mean by the name `optimize`. You'll have to tell it: `from scipy import optimize` near the top of your program.

---

You also call a `main()` function that doesn't exist (at least in your snippet). Typically you'd structure your code more like this:

```
def pval(x, p, i):
    return sum(p[0]*(cos(i*x)) for i in range(1, p[1] + 1))

def main():
    x, y = loadtxt("Data.txt" , unpack=True)
    errfunc = lambda p, x, y: pval(p, x, i) - y # Distance to the target function
    p0 = [49, 100] # Initial guess for the parameters
    p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0[:], args=(x, y))
    # do whatever with p1

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

or just get rid of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section entirely from your code.

Comment: Yep. You need to add the `import` line at the top of your program.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff Thanks for pointing that out; I added that the import should go at the top.